# I want to activate NEAR mainnet instead of the default TESTNET in the NEAR-CLI

Tags: protocols, nearprotocol

I'm trying to activate the NEAR mainnet on the NEAR-CLI but when typing NEAR-ENV=mainnet it says unknown argument.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to set the default to `mainnet` you need to run:

```
export NEAR_ENV=mainnet
```

Alternatively, you can change the network by prepending an environment variable to your command.

Example:

```
NEAR_ENV=mainnet near send ...
```

See the CLI Docs for more info:
https://docs.near.org/tools/near-cli#network-selection

Answer (score 0):

Try out the new https://near.cli.rs. It should be more intuitive.